# request date in apache_request_header()

Tags: php, http, rest, request

I am quite confused whether is it possible to get the request date on HTTP Request. Like in the Response header:

> Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2011 03:03:40 GMT

I tried `var_dump(apache_request_header())` and `print_r($_SERVER)` to attempt if the request date is in there, but no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache_request_header does not return the Request Date/Time. It mainly has the following information

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Host: www.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alivev
```

The best way to find out when the page was requested is to use.

```
$_SERVER[’REQUEST_TIME’]
```

Using $_SERVER is more reliable and uses less resources.

## EDIT

```
$DT = date("D, d M Y H:i:s", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
echo "Time page was requested: ",$DT;
```

Will output something like the folowing

```
Time page was requested: Thu, 20 Oct 2011 23:02:29
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `date()` function in your script,  it is almost the same with request date.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [getallheaders](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php). Also, you could do it server side by calculating the $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] predefined variable.